# Can Trump Make Mexico Pay for the Wall?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Since Trump's daughter is Jewish, I'm *sure* that he would want to do everything according to Halacha. (Ha.) Can he actually make Mexico pay for the wall? I don't mean tax their goods - I mean actually drag Mexico to Beis Din and make them pay.

---

I won't quote the sources because it would take too much space, but here is a summary of some relevant points from [Bava Basra 2a-4b](http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.2a?lang=bi):

- If you hold hezik re'i'ah is a form of damage, partners may force each other to split a courtyard at least 4x8 amos. If it is not a form of damage, they may not split it without each others' consent. However, this is by hezik d'yachid - hezik d'Rabbim everyone holds is considered damage. The type of wall goes after the norm in that part of the world.
- In a garden, you can force where it's normal to build a wall between the two properties no matter the size of the garden.
- Farmland can only be divided with both parties' consent.
- Once consent has been given and both parties make a form of acquisition to that effect, they cannot retract their consent.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Except for the possible unfounded jump from individuals to countries, why is this Purim Torah?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Purim Torah cc @mevaqesh

Comment: @mevaqesh Because I'm looking for equally ridiculous answers

Comment: This does not appear to 
    misinterpret a real Torah concept or Jewish text
or 
    apply a distinctly Torah style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an irrelevant topic. Every single question on the site could receive funny answers, but this tag is not appropriate for all of them.

Comment: @mevaqesh What part of interpreting HaShutfin as referring to nationalities isn't "misinterpreting a real Torah concept"?

Comment: I referenced that in my first comment...I don't know hour one world determine the law for larger groups like countries, if not by noting parallels to smaller groups. Hence my first comment.

Comment: https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14681692_921324807968646_3810114181369819279_n.jpg?oh=dfab7aa1b3203e4cc1fe40e1ff94ec78&oe=5A53F4F2

Comment: pace Alex Minkin (or somebody) on Facebook